# VMware ESXi 7.0 U3j Can't login via root after a few minutes

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, root

I can't login via root user at the moment . If I do a hardware reboot on the server , the problem is solved and I can login for just once before I'm locked out again after like 5 minutes .

I have read similar topics and I have tried the following without success :

- disabling SSH service
- changing password to complex phrases

nothing works . Any ideas what is wrong ?

More Information :

It seems that after reboot , SSH service is activated again . How can I disable it for good ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out so here is the answer for anyone facing the same issue in future :

The login problem is because of SSH service . After a few unsuccessful login attempts which are caused by brute forcing , the root user is locked .

You have to disable the SSH service in VMware . After you disable the service , find SSH service on the services list and right click on it . Go to the policy section and make sure you set it to manual . If you don't choose this policy , SSH service will run again after you reboot the service .

Comment: It seems to be more useful to find out where the failed logins come from and turn that off than to disable SSH access completely.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider Since the SSH port was the default 22 , I assume they were coming from brute forcers . I don't need the SSH service at the moment but if I ever want to enable it again , I'd definitely use a less standard port .